# Take a field from each struct in a list and create an array with lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I defined a structure:

```
public struct STRUC
{
    public int field1;
    public int field2;
    ...
    public int fieldn;
}
```

Now, I have a list of this struct `List<STRUC> l;` and I want to create an array taking the `field2` from each `STRUC` in the list `l`.

For sure with an easy `for`-loop I'm done:

```
int [] arr = new int[l.Count]; 

for(int i=0; i<l.Count; i++)
{
     arr[i] = l[i].field2;
}
```

but I would like to do it with a lambda.

Comment: Mutable structs are evil; you most likely want `STRUC` to either be a class, or be immutable.

Comment: @Servy I used mutable struct beacause I'm marshalling a C++ struct and that seemed to me the easiest way to do it. If you could please suggest me a more appropriate structure to use, you're welcome! (I'm just a newbie!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) and [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx):

```
int[] arr = l.Select(s => s.field2).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var fields = l.Select(x=>x.field2);
```

You will get `IEnumerable` that can iterate over.

```
foreach(var f in fields) {
    //DO SOMETHING ...
}
```

Comment: _"I want to create an array"_

Comment: Yes, I just offered different solution, that **may be** no array will be required, as your answer was already present.